# check if user input according to the format

Tags: c, validation, time, format, user-input

I have a system where the user key in the check in time and check out time in a HH:MM format (code below)

```
//category input here
printf("Check in time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): ");
scanf("%d:%d",&hour,&minute);
printf("Check out time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): ");
scanf("%d:%d",&hour2,&minute2);
```

how can i validate the user input according to the format so that such error wont happen (example below)

```
//example one
category: 2
Check in time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): 1
Check out time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): 3

Driver has to pay: $2

//example 2
category: 1
Check in time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): -1
Check out time (HH:MM 24H FORMAT): 0

Driver has to pay: $1
```

i've tried

```
else if (hour >= 24 || hour2 >= 24 || hour < 0 || hour2 < 0){
    printf("\nERROR! HOUR SHOULD NOT BE 24 OR EXCEED 24 OR LESS THAN 0\n");
}
```

other than that, i have no idea or solution on how to check whether the user is using the correct format :(

thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Yep, typo.  `scanf` returns number of matches, so if you don't match both (2) numbers, you know something's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider reading a *line* of user input with `fgets()`.

Then parse the input *string* with `sscanf()` with a trailing `"%n"`  to record scanning offset - if scanning went that far.

Then followup with range comparisons.

```
char buf[100];
if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)) {
  int n = 0;
  sscanf(buf, "%d :%d %n", &hour,&minute, &n);
  if (n > 0 && minute >= 0 && minute < 60 && hour >= 0 && hour < 24) {
    Success(); // OP's custom code here
  } else {
    Failure(); // OP's custom code here 
  }
}
```

---

To allow `"24:00"` change compare to

```
  if (n > 0 && minute >= 0 && minute < 60 && hour >= 0 && 
      (hour*60 + minute <= 24*60)) {
```

To check for exactly 5 characters and `\n`:

```
  sscanf(buf, "%*1[0-2]%*1[0-9]:%*1[0-5]%*1[0-9]%*[\n]%n", &n);
  if (n == 6) {
    // partial success, now re-scan with "%d:%d" and check positive ranges.
```

Comment: mine said that success(); is not declared in scope(?) do i need to declare a specific header file?

Comment: @DrapeTomania — neither `Success()` nor `success()` is a standard function; you'd have to write it for yourself.  In this context, it is a placeholder for "what should be done when the time is valid".  You'd need something else to deal with `failure()` — reporting the problem and not continuing trying to use the results of a conversion that failed.

Comment: final question, do i need to declare another buf[100] to use with the check out time (hour2 & minute2) or can i use the same variable?

Comment: @DrapeTomania OK to use same buffer.  For me, I'd create a helper function with the buffer in there.  Maybe `int get_time(const char *prompt, int *hour, int *min)` and then call it twice.